# Eclipse 3.3.2 & JDBC (ojdbc7.jar): Building path for jar file doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc, jar

I use in my java app the latest jdbc driver. I added the jar file as described here: http://oopbook.com/java-classpath-2/classpath-in-eclipse/

When running my app in Eclipse it works fine without any problems. BUT creating a jar file (File -> Export -> Jar File) and running it in the Windows Command Line raised the following error: "Please install the Oracle JDBC Driver! java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver...".
I am able to create runnable jar files but have problems with external jar files.

I use Eclipse 3.3.2 (Build id: M20080221-1800) on my machine and its Export functionality to create JAR files.

Comment: First of all, please update your eclipse version if possible... Second, you are probably not including the jdbc library in your jar File... In the export menu you should check the first include libraries radio box

Comment: Can you please comment on which jdbc driver/jar file you have included? Could it be that you have included the wrong driver file?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't (not allowed) update my Eclipse since it is not my private computer. Furthermore, there is no such radio box "Include libraries" (or something similar) in the export menu. Of course I check/select the directory with the libraries in it when choosing the sources to export.

Comment: OK, my solution was to convince the owner of the computer to update Eclipse to the latest version and the problem disappeared.